# No home screen after installing software in Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-center, 18.10

[image]

I think this is a bug. When I install an app through *Ubuntu Software* and then try to go back to the Home screen of *Ubuntu Software* the app is stuck at the screen where software installed notification is made available. For example, I installed **Peek** and tried to go back to the home screen. But it is still stuck at the page where **Peek** is installed as you can see on the GIF attached. Pressing *Back* does not make any impact.

I am using 18.10 + Windows 10 dual boot, with Dash to Panel extension

Comment: Ok I finally got commenting privelage; do you have any custom UI installed? Eg. that "Dash to panel" extension, perhaps that is causing a conflict somehow. I've installed Ubuntu on different computers and never seen that, but I've also never installed any custom GUI stuff.

Comment: I see. Nothing other than Dash to Panel.

Comment: I see this problem too. Really annoying. Closing the application and opening it again - will bring you to the same page again. It refuses to go to the home screen :(

Comment: I have this problem on a clean install of 18.10 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem but I think I figured out a workaround.

Right click on an icon on your dash and click Show Details.  This causes the Ubuntu Software app to open to a different app which allows you to take control again.